# Not uniform behavior of GFS fonts

Tags: fonts, fontsize, greek

For my purpose is to have some greek text with pdflatex (not xelatex), I don't understand the incoherent (?) behavior of GFS fonts. Consider this example

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\newcommand{\GR}[1]{%
  {\fontfamily{artemisia}\selectfont\foreignlanguage{greek}{#1}}%
}

\newcommand{\GRE}[1]{%
  {\fontfamily{bodoni}\selectfont\foreignlanguage{greek}{#1}}%
}

\newcommand{\GREE}[1]{%
  {\fontfamily{neohellenic}\selectfont\foreignlanguage{greek}{#1}}%
}

\newcommand{\GREEK}[1]{%
  {\fontfamily{didot}\selectfont\foreignlanguage{greek}{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}
That time of year you mayst in me behold

\GR{Th| p'anta dido'ush|
ka`i >apolambano'ush| f'usei
<o pepaideum'enos ka`i
a>id'hmwn l'egei;}

\GRE{Th| p'anta dido'ush|
ka`i >apolambano'ush| f'usei
<o pepaideum'enos ka`i
a>id'hmwn l'egei;}

\GREE{Th| p'anta dido'ush|
ka`i >apolambano'ush| f'usei
<o pepaideum'enos ka`i
a>id'hmwn l'egei;}

\GREEK{Th| p'anta dido'ush|
ka`i >apolambano'ush| f'usei
<o pepaideum'enos ka`i
a>id'hmwn l'egei;}

That time of year you mayst in me behold
\end{document}
```

The first three fonts work fine as expected, but the last one not. In fact I receive:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cbfonts-fd/lgrcmr.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ebgaramond/T1EBGaramond-OsF.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/gfsartemisia/t1artemisia.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/gfsartemisia/lgrartemisia.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/gfsbodoni/t1bodoni.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/gfsbodoni/lgrbodoni.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/gfsneohellenic/t1neohellenic.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/gfsneohellenic/lgrneohellenic.fd)

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/didot/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 44.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LGR/didot/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `LGR/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 44.

[1{/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./prova.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

 ){/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/gfsneohellenic/neohelleni
cel.enc}{/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/gfsbodoni/bodoniel.
enc}{/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/gfsartemisia/artemisiae
l.enc}{/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/ebgaramond/ebgm_iymie
h.enc}</usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/ebgaramond/EBGaram
ond12-Regular.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/gfsart
emisia/GFSArtemisia-Regular.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1
/public/gfsbodoni/GFSBodoni-Regular.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fon
ts/type1/public/gfsneohellenic/GFSNeohellenic-Regular.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2
014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cbfonts/grmn1000.pfb>
```

Why didot doesn't compile?
Moreover, I'm unsure if I have to load or not `LGR`. Thanx

=================== **ADDENDUM** ===================

Reading the relative .fd file, I discovered that the real name is `udidot`. That seems to solve! However, the font is too big compared to EB Garamond; so I need something as xelatex `Scale=MatchLowercase` or, in any case, a way to scale the greek font

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.fd` files hard-code a scaling factor for some reason. So the fonts are scaled to `1.04`. You can work around this by using your own definition:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\newcommand{\GR}[1]{%
  {\fontfamily{artemisia}\selectfont\foreignlanguage{greek}{#1}}%
}

\newcommand{\GRE}[1]{%
  {\fontfamily{bodoni}\selectfont\foreignlanguage{greek}{#1}}%
}

\newcommand{\GREE}[1]{%
  {\fontfamily{neohellenic}\selectfont\foreignlanguage{greek}{#1}}%
}

\edef\scaleudidot{s*[.5]}% gives tiny text just to make the effect obvious: increase this to something reasonable (1.04 is default; 1 would be unscaled)
\DeclareFontFamily{LGR}{udidot}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LGR}{udidot}{m}{n}{<-> \scaleudidot gdidotrg6a}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LGR}{udidot}{m}{it}{<-> \scaleudidot golgai6a}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LGR}{udidot}{b}{n}{<-> \scaleudidot gdidotb6a}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LGR}{udidot}{b}{it}{<-> \scaleudidot gdidotbi6a}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LGR}{udidot}{m}{sl}{<-> \scaleudidot gdidoti6a}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LGR}{udidot}{b}{sl}{<-> \scaleudidot gdidotbi6a}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LGR}{udidot}{m}{sc}{<-> \scaleudidot gdidotsc6a}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LGR}{udidot}{m}{ui}{<-> \scaleudidot golgaui6a}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LGR}{udidot}{m}{sco}{<-> \scaleudidot gdidotsco6a}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LGR}{udidot}{bx}{n}{<-> \scaleudidot gdidotb6a}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LGR}{udidot}{bx}{it}{<-> \scaleudidot gdidotbi6a}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LGR}{udidot}{bx}{sl}{<-> \scaleudidot gdidotbi6a}{}


\newcommand{\GREEK}[1]{%
  {\fontfamily{udidot}\selectfont\foreignlanguage{greek}{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}
That time of year you mayst in me behold

\GR{Th| p'anta dido'ush|
ka`i >apolambano'ush| f'usei
<o pepaideum'enos ka`i
a>id'hmwn l'egei;}

\GRE{Th| p'anta dido'ush|
ka`i >apolambano'ush| f'usei
<o pepaideum'enos ka`i
a>id'hmwn l'egei;}

\GREE{Th| p'anta dido'ush|
ka`i >apolambano'ush| f'usei
<o pepaideum'enos ka`i
a>id'hmwn l'egei;}

\GREEK{Th| p'anta dido'ush|
ka`i >apolambano'ush| f'usei
<o pepaideum'enos ka`i
a>id'hmwn l'egei;}

That time of year you mayst in me behold
\end{document}
```

will give the ridiculous

[image: tiny didot]

Change `.5` to something more reasonable according to your needs.

Comment: Thanx, working fine! Maybe I can create a .fd file to put in my personal three. A last  question: I must have `\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}`, i.e. LGR declared? thanx!

Comment: @user41063 Well you are trying to use the LGR encoding i.e. `udidot` uses this encoding for Greek. So, yes, you need to pass that option to `fontenc`. (Or tell LaTeX about the encoding in some other way but I can't think of any reason you'd want to do that.) Is that a problem? And, yes, you could put the replacement code in `lgrudidot.fd` in your tree. Better still, put it in `lgrmydidot.fd` and change `udidot` to `mydidot`. That way, if you later try to compile a document which uses the GFS package, you will still get the expected output.